# Check digits with regex, only the last one element can occur 2 times

Tags: regex

I tried to check a number with regex, where only the last digit can occur twice.

Using javascript as programming language, tried many combinations on https://regex101.com/ but I was able do define only unique characters, like

```
(?:([1-9])(?!.*\1)){8}
```

but I am in trouble with the last one digit.

characterset: [1-9]

important : 0 is not in the characterset, therefore "\d" cannot work, only [1-9].

examples:

```
123456782 -> true, last digit (2) occur twice (EXACTLY), no other repeated digits
189765432 -> false, last digit not repeated previously, only unique digits in it
123456889 -> false, not the last digit repeated
123476782 -> false, not only the last digit repeated
123426282 -> false, last digit repeated more than twice.
```

Any help would be welcomed. How to apply a regex for it?

Comment: What programming language are you using? This is a very tall if not impossible order for regex alone.

Comment: Yes, just wanted to add that this is possible with lookaheads and backreferences, so if you use RE2 or POSIX regexps, you can't get it done with a single pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew For the sake of learning I would be interested in what the regex would look like. So far I've come up with `(\d).*\1$` at https://regex101.com/r/2QgCut/1

Comment: With `(?:([1-9])(?!.*\1)){8}`, you just match a digit from `1` to `9` that does not repeat to the right of the current location 8 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
^(?=[1-9]+([1-9])$)(?!.*(?!\1)(\d).*\2)(?:(?!\1)\d)*\1(?:(?!\1)\d)*\1$
```

A little shortened:

```js
^(?=[1-9]+([1-9])$)(?!.*(?!\1)(\d).*\2)(?:(?:(?!\1)\d)*\1){2}$
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/K9gLdt/5) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/K9gLdt/6).

Note you can use `\d` in the non-initial lookahead since the initial lookahead validates the string format, namely, there can only be two more non-zero digits.

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?=[1-9]+([1-9])$)` - right from the start of string, there should be one or more non-zero digits followed with a non-zero digit at the end of string that is captured into Group 1. We'll be able to refer to this value using the `\1` backreference
- `(?!.*(?!\1)(\d).*\2)` - immediately to the right of the current location, there can be no digit that is not equal to the one captured into Group 1 that is repeated
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `(?:(?!\1)\d)*` - any digit, zero or more occurrences, as many as possible, that is not the one that was captured into Group 1
  - `\1` - the captured digit
- `){2}` - end of the non-capturing group, repeat 2 times
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: That's a mind-bending thing of beauty. :) Given that you've already ensured that only `[1-9]` can be matched in the string, you can streamline a tiny bit more and just use `.` instead of `\d`.